# Apex Trigger to populate custom field on Contract Object with value on contact object

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-field

I have a question for you knowledgeable people

On the contract object we have a field called “Client Director” which is a look up to the contact record.

Field: Client Director
field api : Client_Director__c
Datatype : (Lookup(Contact)

On the contact there is a field called Contact Owner Role

Field: Contact Owner Role
field api : Contact_Owner_Role__c
Datatype : formula 
formula : Owner__r.UserRole.Name

I somehow need to get the owner role on the contact record onto the contract object 
Any ideas how this can be done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a trigger for this. You can do it with a formula on the Contract object. Just create a formula equal to "Client_Director__r.Contact_Owner_Role__c".

Comment: Kyle You are a * :)